# Facing issue while configuring MySql with apache airflow in Hadoop

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, linux, hadoop, airflow

I was trying to install and configure apache airflow on dev Hadoop cluster of a three nodes with below configurations/version:

```
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7
python 3.7.3
anaconda 2
spark 2.45

a)sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ -y
b)sudo yum install libffi-devel mariadb-devel cyrus-sasl-devel -y
c)pip install 'apache-airflow[all]'
d)airflow initdb  -- airflow.cfgfile was created with SQLlite
```

Then I followed below set of commands to configure it with mysql

```
a) rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm 
b) sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo 
c) yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-community-server 
d) systemctl start mysqld.service
```

Done below things at mysql

```
a) CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; 
b) create user 'airflow'@'localhost' identified by 'Airflow123'; 
c) grant all privileges on * . * to 'airflow'@'localhost';
```

here are some details from my `airflow.cfg` file

```
broker_url = sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
result_backend = db+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow:Airflow123@localhost:3306/airflow
executor = CeleryExecutor
```

I am getting below error while running `airflow initdb` commands

```
ImportError: /home/xyz/anaconda2/envs/python3.7.2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: symbol mysql_real_escape_string_quote, 
version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference
```

have set up the .bashrc file as:

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
```

here's my directory created:

```
[xyz@innolx5984 airflow]$ pwd
/home/xyz/airflow
```

When I look for this file "`libmysqlclient`" I have found these many instances.

```
[xyz@innolx5984 airflow]$ find /home/xyz/ -name "*libmysqlclient*"
/home/xyz/anaconda2/pkgs/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-h597af5e_1/lib/libmysqlclient.so
/home/xyz/anaconda2/pkgs/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-h597af5e_1/lib/libmysqlclient.a
/home/xyz/anaconda2/pkgs/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-h597af5e_1/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
/home/xyz/anaconda2/pkgs/mysql-connector-c-6.1.11-h597af5e_1/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.4.0
/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib/libmysqlclient.a
/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib/libmysqlclient.so
/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18.4.0
```

Just adding few more details in case it helps.

```
[xyz@innolx5984 airflow]$ mysql_config
Usage: /home/xyz/an
aconda2/bin/mysql_config [OPTIONS]
Options:
        --cflags         [-I/home/xyz/anaconda2/include ]
        --cxxflags       [-I/home/xyz/anaconda2/include ]
        --include        [-I/home/xyz/anaconda2/include]
        --libs           [-L/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib -lmysqlclient ]
        --libs_r         [-L/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib -lmysqlclient ]
        --plugindir      [/home/xyz`/anaconda2/lib/plugin]
        --socket         [/tmp/mysql.sock]
        --port           [0]
        --version        [6.1.11]
        --variable=VAR   VAR is one of:
                pkgincludedir [/home/xyz/anaconda2/include]
                pkglibdir     [/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib]
                plugindir     [/home/xyz/anaconda2/lib/plugin]

    Looking for some help and suggestion to resolve this
```

issue. I am not too sure whether heading into right direction.

Comment: Suspecting, mariadb causing this issue. Try `yum install python3-devel mysql-devel; pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: we ran this and then airflow initdb.. it's not working and throwing same error.

Comment: `yum remove mariadb-devel`

Comment: it throwing now No Match for argument: mariadb-devel

Comment: Try upgrading Maria db..which version you are currently using of it?

Comment: @franklinsijo .. I have updated it with more details. in case it helps.

Comment: Okay, let me try to reproduce the issue!

Comment: @vikrantrana I followed the same steps as you, I am unable to reproduce the error! The only difference I have is `anaconda3`. I see that you have installed `anaconda2` with `python3` env!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to install Apache Airflow with MySQL using Anaconda3

**1)** Install Pre-requisites

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ -y
yum install libffi-devel mariadb-devel cyrus-sasl-devel -y
dnf install redhat-rpm-config
```

**2)** Install Anaconda3 (comes with Python 3.7.6)

```
yum install libXcomposite libXcursor libXi libXtst libXrandr alsa-lib mesa-libEGL libXdamage mesa-libGL libXScrnSaver
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh 
./Anaconda3-2020.02-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Make sure you do `conda initialize` when prompted during installation. 
This will make sure the correct version of python and pip are used in the subsequent steps.

**3)** Install Apache Airflow

```
pip install apache-airflow[mysql,celery]
```

You can add other subpackages as required. I have included only the ones required for Airflow to use MySQL database as backend.

**4)** Initialize Airflow

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
airflow initdb
```

From here, I have mimicked the steps you have followed to configure MySQL Server

**5)** Install MySQL Server

```
rpm -Uvh https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-3.noarch.rpm 
sed -i 's/enabled=1/enabled=0/' /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo 
yum --enablerepo=mysql80-community install mysql-server 
systemctl start mysqld.service
```

**6)** Login to MySQL and configure database for Airflow

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE airflow CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; 
mysql> CREATE user 'airflow'@'localhost' identified by 'Airflow123'; 
mysql> GRANT ALL privileges on *.* to 'airflow'@'localhost';
```

**7)** Update Airflow configuration file (~/airflow/airflow.cfg)

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://airflow:Airflow123@localhost:3306/airflow
executor = CeleryExecutor
```

**8)** Initialize Airflow

```
airflow initdb
```

Comment: Many Thanks for your kind and humble support. I am accepting this as an answer. Looks like I have to upgrade it to Anaconda3 version. The reason I switched to Anaconda2 version was that I was not able to find hdfs3 module with python 3.7.6 version. will see that later on.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any issues on going further.

Comment: I have followed the same process but same Import error and not able to run these commands dnf install redhat-rpm-config & mysql_config. it says command not found

Comment: Can you try `yum install redhat-rpm-config` instead of `dnf`? Also, is this fresh Anaconda3 installation?

Comment: yeah. I did fresh installation. same Import error. Looks like I need to format the node and then give a try. I could not understand the problem but many thanks for your step by step guidance.

Comment: May be some of the old libraries did not get removed properly. Comment if any issue pops up.

Comment: @ franklinsijo. You were right. I had to remove MySQL completely and anaconda from system and then followed above process and everything went fine. :-) Thanks for your support and help. https://serverfault.com/questions/1011547/facing-issue-while-installing-mysql-with-linux/1012369#1012369

Comment: Great! Finally solved. When I tried to reproduce it was a fresh installation, thus it went smooth without any hiccups.